# Is there a thread safety issue with multiple Java class instances reading the same Map simultaneously?

Tags: java, thread-safety

I have a `Map<Sting, List<Object>>` that can be accessed from multiple Java class instances. This `Map` is sometimes updated by a separate thread once in a while. The instances never write to any of the objects. They simply get one of the `List`s and read the objects in them.

Should I be concerned about thread-safety for this at all? Only one thread is ever writing.

Comment: A priori, yes, if a reader can read at the same time the writer is modifying the structure, you'll run into issues. You should synchronize access and only investigate removing the synchronization if you run into performance issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a word - yes.

Depending on the implementation, `put`ing to a `Map` can change its internal structure, which may cause a concurrent `get` operation to have undefined behavior (e.g., with `HashMap`s, I've seen cases where `get` never returns if a `put` "interrupted" it in the middle).

You should use a `Map` implementation that's threadsafe, such as a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html).

Comment: what if you only use 'get'?

Comment: If you never modify the map, or have some way of ensuring you don't modify the map while calling `get`, any map implementation should be OK.

Comment: @Mureinik You could imagine a hash table implementation optimised for hitting the same key in a bucket each time, moving the entry to be the first for that index if it is not already. That would cause problems.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline that's a good point, thanks! I was implicitly assuming that `get` is a "read-only" operation that doesn't change the state of the map.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Note that Map is an interface, not an implementation. The documentation of several [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) methods mentions:

The default implementation makes no guarantees about synchronization or atomicity properties of this method. Any implementation providing atomicity guarantees must override this method and document its concurrency properties.

Ensure to use a concurrent implementation like [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).